# Is it a good idea to create Implicit classes for our classes in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit

A question on Implicit classes:

I Know Scala supports *Implicit* classes to add functionality to an existing behaviour, but we do have several Implicit classes written for our own classes and I think it's not a good idea to do it, for example:

```
case class AmountInPence(value: Long)

implicit class AmountInPenceOps(amountInPence: AmountInPence) {
  def inPounds: BigDecimal = (BigDecimal(amountInPence.value) / 100).setScale(2)
 //few other defs and vals
   ......
  }
```

It's all our code, meaning we own the ***case class AmountInPence*** too. I think using Implicit classes as a way to add behaviour to our own classes seems the wrong approach to me, but I would like to know you opinions on this

We can add defs and vals in a case class or inside a companion object, but is there a better way to add functionality to case classes instead of using Implicits in the above cases

Thanks

Suresh

Comment: Sadly this is opinion based. However, I will share mine; this design is probably a result of taking to an extreme a common advice in **Scala** which says that you should not couple **case classes** _(or **ADTs** in general)_ with behaviour and rather they should be just data containers and you should have external functions that operate on them _(usually using **pattern matching**)_. While I agree with this advice in general, I have always thought _(and said)_ that simple helpers that basically are just forwarders to the data inside are OK to be defined as normal methods. But again, opinion.

Comment: Implicit classes / extension methods can be used sometimes to overcome difficulties with variance (even if you own the classes you're adding functionality to). For example if you have `class A[+T]` you can't define `def m(t: T)` inside, you'd have to define `def m[S >: T](t: S)`. You can define `implicit class AOps[T](a: A[T]) { def m(t: T) }` instead. This approach is used in https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/hlists.scala#L25-L26

Answer (score 2):

Given that you own the `AmountInPence` class, using an implicit class is pointless. Just add the method directly to `AmountInPence`.